# Override Magento Template

Tags: magento, module, overriding

I'm making a module that needs to override the block/template for the top.phtml so I add in the layout of my module this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <default translate="label" module="page">  
           <reference name="top.menu">
                 <action method="setTemplate"><template>navigationmenu/navigationMenu.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
  </default>
  </layout>
```

It doesn't work, but If I try to reference the header block it changes the template, I don't know if i have to set anything else in my xml.

Edit:
This is the structure in page.xml

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
 <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
  <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
  </block> 
 </block>
</block>
```

I realize I don't need the setTemplate because I need to use my custom Block
It is ok to put my reference under the default tag? Do I need to make another reference?

Also I'm running Magento EE 1.9.1.1 if that helps

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851631/magento-not-recognizing-custom-topmenu-php ?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you need a module for this ?
2. Are you sure using a theme approach is not enough ?
3. Are you sure you need to set a new template with setTemplate() ?
4. I'm not sure you can use setTemplate() outside <block> tag ?
5. crosscheck that "top.menu" block implement the setTemplate() method

Comment: Why you just copy the default template in your theme an change it ?

Comment: I already do what you are suggesting, I need to make a custom module because the navigation being generated according to several options in the backend(this was requested by a client) so I need the custom block and template but I can't for some reason override the default topMenu template